# React - Kendo lib - need to double click to trigger onclick callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-grid

I'm using PanelBar and using component called ParentComponent inside to render Grid like the project I attached https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zqjhpp-ev3ujs?file=app%2Fmain.jsx,app%2FParentComponent.jsx

Here is `App` component:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ParentComponent from './ParentComponent';
import { PanelBar, PanelBarItem } from '@progress/kendo-react-layout';
const App = () => {
    return (
      <PanelBar>
        <PanelBarItem expanded={true}>
          <ParentComponent  />
        </PanelBarItem>
      </PanelBar>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

Here is `ParentComponent` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, GridColumn as Column } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import products from './products.json';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Grid style={{ height: '400px' }} data={[...products]}>
      <Column
        field="ProductID"
        title="ID"
        width="100px"
        cell={(props) => (
          <td>
            <div onClick={()=>{
              console.log("test")
            }}>Click</div>
          </td>
        )}
      />
      <Column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250px" />
      <Column field="Category.CategoryName" title="CategoryName" />
      <Column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" />
      <Column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" />
      <Column
        field="Discontinued"
        cell={(props) => (
          <td>
            <input
              disabled
              type="checkbox"
              checked={props.dataItem[props.field]}
            />
          </td>
        )}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

It works fine until I click on **Click** cell in **ID** column, I need to click it twice to trigger onclick callback log "test" text on the console.

Noted: If I replace

```
<div onClick={() => {
     console.log("test")
}}>Click</div>
```

into a `Link` component of react-router-dom I also have the same issue, I must click twice to trigger it. Please help me! Thank you a lot!

**Updated**: I put useCallback wrapping the callback

```
(props) => (<div onClick={() => console.log(“test”)}>Click<div/>
```

Then it works fine but I do not know the reason why

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your window is focused, so try to click near your cell and then on it, it might actually work.

If not, try to provide onClick into Column itself.

If it doesn't work, I can only suggest that first click might be consumed by PanelBarItem itself, to test it, just remove PanelBarItem with simple div and try click on your cell.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I try to put useCallback wrapping the onclick callback and it works fine but I do not know the reason why  and I need to put onClick in cell because my project requires it

Comment: I can just suggest that by first click it try to expand panel or something and this expansion work conditionally so on your second click it doesn't call any own method. 
And the reason why it not work on first click I think is that inner method just have event.stopPropagation() so that click doesn't reach your div with onClick